# Iteratively calling the index of a list in Django template forloop

Tags: python, django, web

I have multiple images being printed to HTML by a for loop in my template. I want to be able to give them unique ids based on a list of strings. I can't find any way to do this and have up until now been including the ids as properties of the model Image that have to be typed in in admin.

The template code below doesn't work but it explains what I am trying to do.

in views.py

```
ids = ['one','two','three','four']
```

Template:

```
   {% for image in images %}  
<div id ="{{ ids.forloop.counter0 }}"><img src="{{ image.url }}"></div>
          {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need ids

This:

```
{% for image in images %}  
     <div id ="img{{ forloop.counter }}"><img src="{{ image.url }}"></div>
{% endfor %}
```

will output:

```
<div id ="img1"><img src="<url>"></div>
<div id ="img2"><img src="<url>"></div>
.......
```

`forloop.counter`   The current iteration of the loop (`1-indexed`)
`forloop.counter0`  The current iteration of the loop (`0-indexed`)

Comment: A much smarter way to handle this issue! Thanks.

Comment: @AllTheTime if this answers your problem you can accept it as an answer.

Comment: @Bibhas last time i was here it was too early to accept... thanks for the reminder

Comment: @Bibhas thanks. The truth is points means nothing. but still points means something to me. i don't know why?? may be `i am a selfish guy`.

Comment: @suhail it's not about point. This answer being accepted would help the future seekers in making better decisions.